# multiple call to a function that runs async functions: where to put the event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to call a function several times. This function runs an async function inside it. The code is like the following:

```py
 import asyncio

 async def add(x):
     return x + 1


 def my_func(nums):
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()   # where should I put this statement?
     res = loop.run_until_complete(
         asyncio.gather(*[add(x) for x in nums]))

     return res


 def main():
     batch1 = [1, 2, 3]
     batch2 = [4, 5, 6]

     print(my_func(batch1))
     print(my_func(batch2))


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

My question is where should I put the statement `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`. Should I put inside `my_func` or just put it in the global level and make it global variable, e.g., put it below `import asyncio`.

What is the best practice?

Comment: The way you did it is perfectly fine, and almost certainly superior to using a global variable. You can consider using `asyncio.run()` instead and eliminate that statement and the `loop` variable altogether. The downside is that each call to `my_func` would set up and tear down a separate event loop on each invocation, which might be more expensive.

Comment: Note that, in general, hiding asyncio behind a synchronous API might cause problems if `my_func` is ever itself called from inside an event loop. Event loop nesting is not allowed, so that will fail with an exception.